# R ggplot2 and direct.label() - Is there a workaround for the "eval error"?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In R ggplot2, I'd like to use the directlabels package to label some contours, just as is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38154679/r-adding-legend-and-directlabels-to-ggplot2-contour-plot). Unfortunately the examples given there, or [here](http://directlabels.r-forge.r-project.org/), or [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/directlabels/versions/2017.03.31/topics/geom_dl), or anywhere, are not working. They all throw the following error:

Error in eval(quote({ : could not find function "eval"

Looking around stack overflow it seems the problem has something to do with the latest update to ggplot2 [using ggproto instead of proto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35462240/error-in-evalexpr-envir-enclos-could-not-find-function-eval).

Is there a quick fix that can get the examples working again?

Comment: Have you tried with a clear and new workspace? Latest ggplot version, etc.

Comment: If the problem persists, session data and maybe reproducible data would be useful